# Are there any third party displays that have similar resolution and image quality to the Thunderbolt Display?

Tags: hardware, display, hardware-recommendation, thunderbolt-display, third-party

The cinema and thunderbolt displays are expensive. As such, I'm thinking about a third party display to attach to my MacBook. I currently have a Dell 24" monitor, but the color is waaaay off. The IT guy at work was telling me about this other 27" monitor that has the number of pixels and IPS, just like the 27" iMac. (I'm still wondering about color temperature etc.)

So, are there any third party monitors that are similar, if not identical (casing and stand/mount aside) to the Thunderbolt display?

Comment: Did you know you can fix the color on your external monitor? Go into Displays Preferences, go to the window on your external monitor, choose the Color tab, and hit Calibrate. The wizard will then step you through the process of fixing the colors of the monitor.

Comment: Which Dell screen do you own?

Answer (score 3):

The last time I checked up on this, about 6 months ago, the only monitor I could find that matches the Apple display was the [Dell UltraSharp U2412M](http://accessories.euro.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=uk&l=en&s=dhs&cs=ukdhs1&sku=609020&~ck=baynoteSearch&baynote_bnrank=4&baynote_irrank=0). However it's a 24" and it wasn't that cheap. Dell does however have a bigger model in the range which is the [Dell UltraSharp U2711](http://accessories.euro.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=uk&l=en&s=dhs&cs=ukdhs1&sku=609020&~ck=baynoteSearch&baynote_bnrank=4&baynote_irrank=0).

[image: Dell UltraSharp U2711]

Both are brilliant.

<sub>I ended up buying a 27" iMac and stopped looking further</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the [Samsung S27A950D 27-Inch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004Z75LX0) ($700)

[image]

or the [Dell UltraSharp U2711](http://accessories.ap.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=au&cs=audhs1&l=en&s=dhs&sku=210-31399&redirect=1) (if you're not using this one already)  ($899)
[image]